# Como borrar el archivo sobrante después de unir dos archivos?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio, debo crear 2 archivos y escribir cosas en su interior, aprox 2 lineas de texto en cada uno y a continuación debo crear un 3er fichero y copiar todas las lineas de los dos anteriores ficheros en el 3ero y borrar los dos anteriores, yo consigo crear correctamente el 3er fichero y que se introduzcan los datos, pero solo se me borra el primer fichero, el segundo sigue estando en la carpeta como sería esto ?

**adjunto codigo:**

```
public static void combinarFichero(String directorio,String ficherorUno, String ficheroDos) throws IOException {

            //llamo a los metodos de insertar fichero

            //creo variables para cada una de las rutas que voy a usar

           //llamo dos buffreader y les asigno un nombre y llamo un buffered reader  

            //creo 3 clases file y les asigno una ruta

            //si no existen los file 1 y 2 previamente creados se crean y nos avisa si existen o no.

            //creamos el 3er fichero

            try {
               //a los 2 buffreader se le asigna el file con su ruta y al file reader lo mismo

                copiar(buffWrite, buffRead);
                copiar(buffWrite, buffReadDos);


            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                if(buffWrite != null)
                    buffWrite.close();
                if(buffRead != null)
                    buffRead.close();

                new File(RutaOriginalDos).delete(); //elimina los dos primeros archivos que hemos creado
                new File(RutaOriginal).delete(); 
            }
    }

    private static void copiar(BufferedWriter bw, BufferedReader br) throws IOException{

        String linea=br.readLine();
        while(linea!=null){

            bw.write(linea);

            linea=br.readLine();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > yo consigo crear correctamente el 3er fichero y que se introduzcan los datos, pero solo se me borra el primer fichero, el segundo sigue estando en la carpeta como sería esto

El problema radica en este bloque de código:

```java
finally 
{
    if(buffWrite != null)
        buffWrite.close();
    if(buffRead != null)
        buffRead.close();

    new File(RutaOriginalDos).delete(); 
    new File(RutaOriginal).delete(); 
}
```

Se te olvidó cerrar los recursos de `buffReadDos`.

Es decir, el código debería ser así:

```java
finally 
{
    if(buffWrite != null)
        buffWrite.close();
    if(buffRead != null)
        buffRead.close();
    if(buffReadDos != null)
        buffReadDos.close();

    new File(RutaOriginalDos).delete(); 
    new File(RutaOriginal).delete(); 
}
```

Si no cierras los recursos, no podrás eliminar el segundo archivo y el método `delete` retornará `false`.

Lo puedes comprobar con este código de ejemplo:

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File f = new File("nombres.txt");

        var b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("nombres.txt"));

        System.out.println(f.delete());
    }

}
```

Resultado en pantalla:

```java
false
```

Comment: Era exactamente esto!!!! que fallo tan tonto, estoy un poco mareada con esto de los archivos, Muchisimas gracias!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Después de crear el archivo puedes eliminarlos archivos usando el método `delete()`:

```
  ...
  f3.createNewFile();
  ...
  //Elimina archivos.
  f1.delete();
  f2.delete();
  ...
```

Me refiero a que realices esto en tu `finally`:

```
    finally {
        if(buffWrite != null)
            buffWrite.close();
        if(buffRead != null)
            buffRead.close();
        if(buffReadDos != null)
            buffReadDos.close();

        //new File(RutaOriginalDos).delete(); 
        //new File(RutaOriginal).delete(); 
        //Elimina archivos.
        f1.delete();
        f2.delete();
    }
```

Comment: @azucarilla revisa el bloque finally que agrego y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Justo me paso lo que comenta @MrDave1999 daba un error en consola. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)